# Scala has sleep like Thread.sleep that not blocking main thread?

Tags: multithreading, scala

In case i don't want to use `Thread.sleep` is there is another way to sleep without blocking main `Thread` ?

Comment: You want to sleep without sleeping? Purpose of sleeping is to block the thread. You need to elaborate on what you want to do and why.

Comment: `Future { Thread.sleep(millis) }` does what you ask. Seems pretty useless though, as @Łukasz points out.

Comment: I am using selenium so from time to time i want to sleep several seconds so what is the different between the both ?

Comment: The thing is that `sleep` and `blocking` are synonyms. So when you ask "how to sleep without blocking", that just does not make any sense at all.

Comment: OK, and what about what i asked ?

Comment: Your question is still unclear. "I am using selenium so from time to time i want to sleep several seconds". Then go ahead and sleep several seconds. What is the problem here? Why don't you want to block, what else you expect to happen that `Thread.sleep` is not capable to provide for you?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `Thread.sleep`. As far as I know, Selenium starts browser in a separate process and communicates with it via socket so if you block a Java thread it doesn't affect the browser, browser continues to load its stuff independently.